# Visual Studio custom tasks not showing in task view

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

For many years, I use custom tasks defined under **Tools>Options>Task list**
Comments marked accordingly are supposed to show up in the "Task List" view, but only the build-in task types like "**TODO**" or "**HACK**" appear.
What I have tried so far without success:

- Delete and re-entered my custom tasks in **Tools>Options>Task** list
- Closed and reopened the Task List view
- Installed the newest version of VS (16.6.5)
- Compared CurrentSettings.vssettings with earlier backups without finding any differences

My single most important tag is named "TEMP", but the name does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that this is a [known bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1010242/custom-tokens-not-displayed-in-task-list.html) which will be fixed in version 16.7. It was introduced with version 16.6.